# p5.js: Why is my image duplicating every time I use the keyPressed() function?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am trying to navigate the legoman image across the canvas using the arrow keys. However, the image seems to duplicate instead (see image).

[legoman p5.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryHD6.png)

How do I get the image to move without leaving a trail of images behind?

See code:

```
function keyPressed() {
  if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
    y = y - 10;
  } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
    y = y + 10;
  }
  if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
    x = x - 10;
  } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
    x = x + 10;
  }

  if (keyCode === RETURN) {
    background(255);
  }
}
```

Also here is the link to my file if that helps: https://editor.p5js.org/emmajaneculhane/sketches/NDWUd0-Vj

Comment: Depends on how it's actually being drawn--is it being *moved*, or is it being drawn at the new coordinates (which would mean it needs to be erased at the current coords first)?

Comment: You are probably drawing with a canvas... You need to clear the canvas before drawing on it each frame with `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`

Comment: @DaveNewton it's not under draw(), if that's what you mean? Would it be helpful to post the full code or file?

Comment: thanks @NolanCarpenter, should I put that code into the keyPressed function?

Comment: You should use this code to clear the canvas right before you redraw the lego man.

Comment: @NolanCarpenter sorry I'm new to this! But where in the code do I put it exactly?

Comment: I've added my file too if that helps

Comment: I apologize... I completely missed the fact you were using p5.js! Simply store the current background in a variable, then in the `keyPressed` function, call `background(currentBackground)` I created my own pj5.js here: https://editor.p5js.org/nmcarp99/sketches/NfG0mJO6A

Comment: @NolanCarpenter thank you so much!! You saved my project and sanity :D

Comment: Why are people constantly answering questions in the comments ‍♂️? /me votes to close not reproducible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is no longer present in the p5 editor sketch you've shared.

That is because you're calling

```
background(currentBackground);
```

in `keyPressed()` in that version.

Indeed, `background()` clears the previously rendered image with a flat colour which is the behaviour you want to avoid trails.

You would need to set `currentBackground` to a different value once you click one of the 8 colour circles.

For example:

```js
if (dRed < 30 / 2 && mouseIsPressed) {
    currentBackground = redB;
  }
```

instead of:

```
if (dRed < 30 / 2 && mouseIsPressed) {
    background(redB);
  }
```

The same logic would apply to the rest of the colour circles.

Additionally if you want to make the keys a bit more responsive you can check if a key is pressed in `draw()`:

```js
function draw() {
  
  if(keyIsPressed){
    if (keyCode === UP_ARROW) {
      y = y - 10;
    } else if (keyCode === DOWN_ARROW) {
      y = y + 10;
    }
    if (keyCode === LEFT_ARROW) {
      x = x - 10;
    } else if (keyCode === RIGHT_ARROW) {
      x = x + 10;
    }
  }
  
  background(currentBackground);
  //...the rest of your draw code goes here

}
```

It might also help to have some boundary conditions so the LEGO figure doesn't go outside of bounds (e.g. only increment `x` if it's greater than 0 and smaller than the width of the sketch, same applies for `y`)